# how can i fix the error (#11601: Request for billing address failed) of paypal

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal

I am using magento 1.9 during the setup of paypal at store i am getting an error

#### Billing address request is not enabled for merchant (#11601: Request for billing address failed).###

I am stuck on this and i have tried every thing. so please any one can help me in this problem

Comment: Have you gone into your Paypal account and set this up? It's not a Magento issue until it has been enabled.

Comment: Any idea where to set this? I've been trying for literally years to get this setting to work, PayPal support don't even seem to know what I'm talking about and I can't find the setting in live or sandbox. Other posts on SO suggest that it can only be enabled by PayPal staff - but they have never heard of it.

Answer (score 10):

I had this problem and I changed this in System>Configuration>payment methods>Paypal express checkout (configure)>Basic Settings - PayPal Express Checkout>advanced settings>require customer’s billing address. Set this to No

My example is in my site [www.realleather.com.au](http://www.realleather.com.au)

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue as well and called PayPal support several times. Finally, a support representative said he turned the option on in our account, but I am still seeing the error.

I found this page explaining error code [#11601](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ2035&expand=true&locale=en_US):

> https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ2035&expand=true&locale=en_US

The issue is regarding the option [`SetCustomerBillingAgreement`](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/archive/api/merchant/SetCustomerBillingAgreement_API_Operation_NVP/), which initiates a [billing agreement](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/#billing-agreements) and has been **deprecated since v54.0** of the API (view [Merchant API Release Notes](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/release-notes/merchant/)).

We are on Magento `2.1.7` and recently billing address information stopped being returned from PayPal API requests - the **Require Customer's Billing Address** option seemed promising.

I am going to leave the **`Stores > Configuration > Sales > Payment Methods > PayPal Express Checkout > Advanced Settings > Require Customer's Billing Address`** option set to **`No`** and look further into it.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm using Magento v1.9, I tried the same but it seems not yet fixed, the issue is same.
Sales->Paymentmethods->PayPal Payment Solutions->Configure->Required PayPal Settings->Basic Settings->Advanced Settings->Require Customer's Billing Address set as "No"

Any Help??