# Received paypal error message?

Tags: paypal

I received this error message when trying out my new shop:

PayPal gateway has rejected request. Billing address request is not enabled for merchant (#11601: Request for billing address failed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this in System>Configuration>payment methods>Paypal express checkout (configure)>Basic Settings - PayPal Express Checkout>advanced settings>require customer’s billing address. Set this to No Hope it helps

Comment: YOU ROCK!! Worked like a charm Thanks a bunch

Comment: Ok Cool kindly give up my answer:)

Answer (score 0):

We are using Magento `2.1.7` and recently experienced the same issue.

In short:

> The issue is regarding the option [`SetCustomerBillingAgreement`](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/archive/api/merchant/SetCustomerBillingAgreement_API_Operation_NVP/), which initiates a [billing agreement](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/#billing-agreements) and has been **deprecated since v54.0** of the API.

I have more details in [my answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/190935/27104) to the related question [#31887](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31887/how-can-i-fix-the-error-11601-request-for-billing-address-failed-of-paypal/190935#190935).